# Flutter - New Relic does not trace the API Requests from Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, newrelic

What I want:

I want to Integrate **[New Relic](https://newrelic.com)** in Flutter App to trace the GraphQL API Requests executed from my App (For GraphQL Requests I've used [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter) Package)

What I have done:

I have added Native  Code for New Relic Integration in Android & iOS

I've added a custom plugin for New Relic (Found the plugin from [here](https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/flutter-support-in-nr/176199))

As per the New Relic Android SDK I have added following code in **MainActivity.kt** File

```
NewRelic.withApplicationToken("-------APIKEY------")
  .withAnalyticsEvents(true).withDistributedTraceListener(traceListener)
  .withCrashReportingEnabled(true).withInteractionTracing(true)
  .withDefaultInteractions(true).withHttpResponseBodyCaptureEnabled(true)
  .start(this.applicationContext)
         

        NewRelic.enableFeature(FeatureFlag.NetworkRequests)
        NewRelic.enableFeature(FeatureFlag.NetworkErrorRequests)
        NewRelic.enableFeature(FeatureFlag.DefaultInteractions)
        NewRelic.enableFeature(FeatureFlag.InteractionTracing)
        NewRelic.enableFeature(FeatureFlag.DistributedTracing)
        NewRelic.enableFeature(FeatureFlag.HttpResponseBodyCapture)
```

As per New Relic iOS SDK, I followed the Steps listed [here](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-ios/ios-sdk-api/ios-sdk-api-guide/)

Issues I am facing:

1. API Requests executed from Flutter Code are not getting logged in New Relic Dashboard
2. Only API Requests executed from a Flutter Package which uses MethodChannel for API Requests are logged in New Relic Dashboard